# VerneMQ on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, mqtt-vernemq, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install VerneMQ on a Kubernetes cluster over Oracle OCI usign Helm chart.

The Kubernetes infrastructure seems to be up and running, I can deploy my custom microservices without a problem.

I'm following the instructions from https://github.com/vernemq/docker-vernemq

Here the steps:

- `helm install --name="broker" ./` from helm/vernemq directory

the output is:

```
NAME:   broker
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Mar  1 11:07:37 2019
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/RoleBinding
NAME            AGE
broker-vernemq  1s

==> v1/Service
NAME                     TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)   AGE
broker-vernemq-headless  ClusterIP  None          <none>       4369/TCP  1s
broker-vernemq           ClusterIP  10.96.120.32  <none>       1883/TCP  1s

==> v1/StatefulSet
NAME            DESIRED  CURRENT  AGE
broker-vernemq  3        1        1s

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME              READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
broker-vernemq-0  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         1s

==> v1/ServiceAccount
NAME            SECRETS  AGE
broker-vernemq  1        1s

==> v1/Role
NAME            AGE
broker-vernemq  1s


NOTES:
1. Check your VerneMQ cluster status:
  kubectl exec --namespace default broker-vernemq-0 /usr/sbin/vmq-admin cluster show

2. Get VerneMQ MQTT port
  echo "Subscribe/publish MQTT messages there: 127.0.0.1:1883"
  kubectl port-forward svc/broker-vernemq 1883:1883
```

but when I do this check

`kubectl exec --namespace default broker-vernemq-0 vmq-admin cluster show`

I got

```
Node 'VerneMQ@broker-vernemq-0..default.svc.cluster.local' not responding to pings.
command terminated with exit code 1
```

I think there is something wrong with subdomain (the double dots without nothing between them)

Whit this command

```
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name | head -1) -c kubedns
```

The last log line is

```
I0301 10:07:38.366826       1 dns.go:552] Could not find endpoints for service "broker-vernemq-headless" in namespace "default". DNS records will be created once endpoints show up.
```

I've also tried with this  custom yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: vernemq
  labels:
    app: vernemq
spec:
  serviceName: vernemq
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vernemq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vernemq
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vernemq
        image: erlio/docker-vernemq:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 1883
            name: mqtt
          - containerPort: 8883
            name: mqtts
          - containerPort: 4369
            name: epmd
        env:
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS
          value: "off"
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_DISCOVERY_KUBERNETES
          value: "1"
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_APP_LABEL
          value: "vernemq"
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_PASSWD__PASSWORD_FILE
          value: "/etc/vernemq-passwd/vmq.passwd"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: vernemq-passwd
            mountPath: /etc/vernemq-passwd
            readOnly: true

      volumes:
      - name: vernemq-passwd
        secret:
          secretName: vernemq-passwd
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vernemq
  labels:
    app: vernemq
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: vernemq
  ports:
  - port: 4369
    name: epmd
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mqtt
  labels:
    app: mqtt
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: vernemq
  ports:
  - port: 1883
    name: mqtt
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mqtts
  labels:
    app: mqtts
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: vernemq
  ports:
  - port: 8883
    name: mqtts
```

Any suggestion?

Many thanks
Jack

Comment: I've also tried to deploy VerneMQ on a local cluster with one master and two workers (https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/oracle-vm-virtualbox-get-kubernetes-cluster-running-in-minutes) and I get the same error:

`Node 'VerneMQ@vernemq-0.default.svc.cluster.local' not responding to pings.
command terminated with exit code 1`

The only difference is that in this configuration there isn't a subdomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the Docker image. The suggestion on github is to built your own image or use the later VerneMQ image (after 1.6.x) where it has been fixed.

Suggestion mentioned here: https://github.com/vernemq/docker-vernemq/pull/92

Pull-Request for a possible fix: https://github.com/vernemq/docker-vernemq/pull/97

EDIT:

I only got it to work without helm. Using `kubectl create -f ./cluster.yaml`, with the following `cluster.yaml`:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: vernemq
  namespace: default
spec:
  serviceName: vernemq
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vernemq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vernemq
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: vernemq
      containers:
      - name: vernemq
        image: erlio/docker-vernemq:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1883
          name: mqttlb
        - containerPort: 1883
          name: mqtt
        - containerPort: 4369
          name: epmd
        - containerPort: 44053
          name: vmq
        - containerPort: 9100
        - containerPort: 9101
        - containerPort: 9102
        - containerPort: 9103
        - containerPort: 9104
        - containerPort: 9105
        - containerPort: 9106
        - containerPort: 9107
        - containerPort: 9108
        - containerPort: 9109
        env:
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_DISCOVERY_KUBERNETES
          value: "1"
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_APP_LABEL
          value: "vernemq"
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
           fieldRef:
             fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ERLANG__DISTRIBUTION__PORT_RANGE__MINIMUM
          value: "9100"
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ERLANG__DISTRIBUTION__PORT_RANGE__MAXIMUM
          value: "9109"
        - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_INSECURE
          value: "1"
        # only allow anonymous access for development / testing purposes!
        # - name: DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS
        #   value: "on"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vernemq
  labels:
    app: vernemq
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: vernemq
  ports:
  - port: 4369
    name: empd
  - port: 44053
    name: vmq
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mqttlb
  labels:
    app: mqttlb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: vernemq
  ports:
  - port: 1883
    name: mqttlb
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mqtt
  labels:
    app: mqtt
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: vernemq
  ports:
  - port: 1883
    name: mqtt
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: vernemq
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: endpoint-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["endpoints", "deployments", "replicasets", "pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: endpoint-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: vernemq
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: endpoint-reader
```

Needs a few seconds to get the pods ready.

Comment: I've used helm's chart wtih the latest VerneMQ image (1.7.1) but the problem still remains.

Comment: Can you add your yaml file to the post?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the original post!

Comment: Do you get the same error when you remove the `namespace: default` from the metadata?

Comment: I edited my post with a yaml that worked for me, the only big differences are setting the env variable DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_INSECURE to "1" and adding the ServiceAccount, Role and Rolebinding.

Comment: I've tried your configuration and now the command `kubectl exec vernemq-0 -- vmq-admin cluster show` works! Now I've to understand the `DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_INSECURE` option. Many thanks :)

Comment: Look into SSL certificates with kubernetes [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/).

Used with VerneMQ like in [these examples](https://github.com/vernemq/docker-vernemq/issues/64).

Happy to help! You can accept the comment, if you think the question has been answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the environment variables "DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_APP_LABEL" and "DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE". That's what worked for me.

Comment: I've the same problem using my yaml (with DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_APP_LABEL and  DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE labels) instead the helm's chart.

Comment: The latest Docker image now uses DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_LABEL_SELECTOR, as mentioned by the earlier answer.

Comment: I've just tried with DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_LABEL_SELECTOR but the error remains.

Answer (score -1):

Default Selector name is **vernemMQ**,

You can override it with environment variable   `DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_LABEL_SELECTOR` and pass the value as **app=name**

```
DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_LABEL_SELECTOR="app={Name}"
```

for Example:

```
DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_LABEL_SELECTOR="app=demo"
```

Reference to read:

[Dockerfile from VerneMQ](http://%20https://hub.docker.com/r/vernemq/vernemq/dockerfile)